# How do I extract answer from a google form and send it via email?

Tags: google-apps-script

My base code is done so that I can route email depending from what the user selected.

But now I want to get the answer from the user google form and send it to his email by changing the body of the email.

- How do I do that?
- I have tried some solution I have found in forums but it does not work for my application.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMDVU.png)

Comment: Please don't share code as images, copy-paste it here and format it nicely so it's easy for other people to understand it.

Comment: You can use onFormSubmit trigger for Spreadsheet and all the data is in the event object in an array named values

Answer (score 0):

In it's simplest of forms:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  let r = 'recipent email';
  let s = 'subject';
  let m = e.values.join('\n')
  GmailApp.sendEmail(r,s,m)
}
```

You need to create onFormSubmit trigger with onMyFormSubmit being the handler function.